# How can I write the text file content equal to file name?

Tags: windows, powershell, text, cmd, notepad

I have 100 empty text files I need to make their content equal to their file names.
Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: More details please. All the files are in same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that is what you are looking for, but you can do it using the "forfiles" command:

```
forfiles /M *.txt /C "cmd /c if @fsize equ 0 echo @file > @file"
```

For Example: a.txt will contain "a.txt".

**Update:**

Updated to only take text files with a size of zero (empty).

Comment: @Stefan: much better ^^

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion 
    for %%a in (*.txt) do if %%~za equ 0 >"%%~fa" echo(%%~nxa
```

For each txt file, if its size is 0 write the name and extension of the file as its content

To use from command line, unescape the percent signs

```
for %a in (*.txt) do if %~za equ 0 >"%~fa" echo(%~nxa
```

Answer (score 1):

Since PowerShell was tagged on this...

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\temp\folder | Where-Object{ $_.Length -eq 0} | ForEach-Object{Set-Content -Path $_ -Value $_.Name}
```

Get all the files in the directory `E:\temp\folder` that have a zero length ( contain no data ). Set the content on each of those files to the file name.